# Add custom field value after selected WooCommerce product variation price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price, product-variations

We have added a select field to simple products, so that we can define the price unit and display the unit after the price on the single product page. This works fine.

Additionally we have added a select field for variable products to define the price unit of each variation. This price unit should be displayed after the variation price on the product page:

```
<?php

function mytheme_woo_add_custom_variation_fields( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {

    echo '<div class="options_group form-row form-row-full">';

    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_variable_select_field', true );
    if( empty( $value ) ) $value = '';
    // Select
    woocommerce_wp_select(
        array(
            'id'      => '_variable_select_field[' . $variation->ID . ']',
            'label'   => __( 'Mengeneinheit', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value' => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, '_variable_select_field', true ),
            'options' => array(
                ''          => __( 'ohne', 'woocommerce' ),
                'Stück'     => __( 'Stück', 'woocommerce' ),
                'Paar'      => __( 'Paar', 'woocommerce' ),
                'Karton'   => __( 'Karton', 'woocommerce' ),
                'Packung'   => __( 'Packung', 'woocommerce' ), 
                'Set'   => __( 'Set', 'woocommerce' ),              
                'lfm'       => __( 'Laufmeter', 'woocommerce' ),
                'm²'        => __( 'm2', 'woocommerce' ),
                )
        )
    );
    echo '</div>';
}

// Variations tab
add_action( 'woocommerce_variation_options_pricing', 'mytheme_woo_add_custom_variation_fields', 10, 3 );


// Add custom field for variations
function load_variation_settings_fields( $variations ) {
$variations['_variable_select_field'] = get_post_meta( $variations[ 'variation_id' ], '_variable_select_field', true );
  return $variations;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'load_variation_settings_fields' );

//Save variable product field
function mytheme_woo_add_custom_variation_fields_save( $post_id ){

    $woocommerce_select_field = $_POST['_variable_select_field'][ $post_id ];
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_variable_select_field', esc_attr( $woocommerce_select_field ) );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'mytheme_woo_add_custom_variation_fields_save', 10, 2 );


/* Display the custom field after the price */
function mytheme_display_woo_custom_fields( $price ){
    global $post, $product;

    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ){
        $variation_price_unit = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_variable_select_field', true );
        $price .= $variation_price_unit;
    }
        return $price;  
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'mytheme_display_woo_custom_fields', 15 );
```

However, it does not work , I cannot find the right way to do that.
Can anyone let me know how to display the saved value from the product variation after the price?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple code snippet will display after selected variation price the related price unit as follows:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'display_price_unit_after_variations_price_html', 10, 3) ;
function display_price_unit_after_variations_price_html( $data, $product, $variation ) {
    if ( $mengeneinheit = $variation->get_meta('_variable_select_field') )
        $data['price_html'] .= ' ' . $mengeneinheit;

    return $data;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

You should rename the key `_variable_select_field` everywhere with for example `_mengeneinheit` as it will be more explicit (or in english `_price_unit`).

Comment: Thank you for your help LoicTheAztec!